# SFML foreground collision

Tags: colors, collision, sfml, foreground, intersect

Ive been trying to make an RPG game on SFML and now Im kind of struggling on the collisions. My problem is quiet simple, I have this 2 layers, Background and Foreground. Background just acts as a background image and Foreground png image is supposed to act as the collisions, having the part where the character is supposed to walk completely free (transparent) and keeping the rest of the structures to use as collisions (Background image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdUgn.jpg  Im making the floor transparent while keeping the rest). Ive tried using the getGlobalBounds().intesect with the character sprite without any succes. I wanna keep it as simple as possible, here is what I have until now:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Piso1.h"

using namespace std;
Piso1::Piso1(){

};

int Piso1::Draw(RenderWindow &window, Event &evento)
{
srand(time(nullptr));
Soundtrack.openFromFile("../Scenes/Piso1/Sounds/Neon District.wav");
    Soundtrack.setLoop(true);
    Soundtrack.play();

Texture BGTexture;
    BGTexture.loadFromFile("../Scenes/Piso1/Graphics/piso1background.png");
Sprite Background;
    Background.setTexture(BGTexture);
    Background.setScale(8,7.5);
    Background.setPosition(BackX,BackY);


Texture FGTexture;
    FGTexture.loadFromFile("../Scenes/Piso1/Graphics/piso1foreground.png");
Sprite Foreground;
    Foreground.setTexture(FGTexture);
    Foreground.setScale(8,7.5);
    Foreground.setPosition(BackX,BackY);

Texture ProtaTextura;
    ProtaTextura.loadFromFile("../Scenes/Piso1/Graphics/pSprite.png");
    IntRect SpriteBx(0,0,34,47);
Sprite Protagonista(ProtaTextura,SpriteBx);
    Protagonista.setPosition((window.getSize().x)/2.35,(window.getSize().y)/3);
    Protagonista.setScale(3,3);

while (window.isOpen()) {
    while (window.pollEvent(evento)) {
        switch (evento.type) {
            case Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case Event::KeyPressed:
                EncounterValue = rand()%1000;
                if(EncounterValue > 5){
                    if(evento.key.code == Keyboard::Down) {
                        BackY -= 10;
                        Background.move(0,-10);
                        Foreground.move(0,-10);
                        //this is my failed attempt
                        if(Protagonista.getLocalBounds().intersects(Foreground.getLocalBounds()))
                        {
                            Collision.openFromFile("../Scenes/Piso1/Sounds/oof.ogg");
                            Collision.play();
                            BackY += 10;
                            Background.move(0, 10);
                            Foreground.move(0, 10);
                        }

                        if(clock1.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds()>64){
                            SpriteBx.top = 0;
                            if (SpriteBx.left == 0)
                                SpriteBx.left = 34;
                            else if (SpriteBx.left==34)
                                SpriteBx.left= 68;
                            else if (SpriteBx.left== 68)
                                SpriteBx.left= 102;
                            else
                                SpriteBx.left=0;
                            Protagonista.setTextureRect(SpriteBx);
                            clock1.restart();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (evento.key.code == Keyboard::Up) {
                        BackY += 10;
                        Background.move(0,10);
                        Foreground.move(0,10);
                        if (clock1.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds()>64)
                        {
                            SpriteBx.top = 152;
                            if (SpriteBx.left == 0)
                                SpriteBx.left = 34;
                            else if (SpriteBx.left==34)
                                SpriteBx.left= 68;
                            else if (SpriteBx.left== 68)
                                SpriteBx.left= 102;
                            else
                                SpriteBx.left=0;
                            Protagonista.setTextureRect(SpriteBx);
                            clock1.restart();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(evento.key.code == Keyboard::Left) {
                        BackX += 10;
                        Background.move(10,0);
                        Foreground.move(10,0);
                        if (clock1.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds()>64)
                        {
                            SpriteBx.top = 53;
                            if (SpriteBx.left == 0)
                                SpriteBx.left = 34;
                            else if (SpriteBx.left==34)
                                SpriteBx.left= 68;
                            else if (SpriteBx.left== 68)
                                SpriteBx.left= 102;
                            else
                                SpriteBx.left=0;
                            Protagonista.setTextureRect(SpriteBx);
                            clock1.restart();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(evento.key.code == Keyboard::Right){
                        BackX -= 10;
                        Background.move(-10,0);
                        Foreground.move(-10,0);
                        if (clock1.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds()>64)
                        {
                            SpriteBx.top = 104;
                            if (SpriteBx.left == 0)
                                SpriteBx.left = 34;
                            else if (SpriteBx.left==34)
                                SpriteBx.left= 68;
                            else if (SpriteBx.left== 68)
                                SpriteBx.left= 102;
                            else
                                SpriteBx.left=0;
                            Protagonista.setTextureRect(SpriteBx);
                            clock1.restart();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(evento.key.code == Keyboard::C){
                        Soundtrack.stop();
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Soundtrack.stop();
                    return 0;
                }
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(Foreground);
        window.draw(Background);
        window.draw(Protagonista);
        window.display();
    }
}
}
```

I think whats happening is that when I want to do the if it takes the whole png instead of just the parts I want as collision. I also wanted to try color collision but I really dont know how to implement it, Im kind of new to SFML. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do I understand you right that Foreground is a texture which contains information about passable and impassable areas for your Protagonista?

Comment: Yeah, its the same as Background but with the difference that the impassable area (Eg: walls) are completely filled with black while the passable areas (floor) is filled with nothing (see image on the link as refference).

Comment: Okay. Another question: though it is possible to do it this way, I would not recommend this approach because sooner or later you'll run into scalability (collision checks would fail if you'll scale the picture) and performance issues. I can show how to set walls in text format and how to use box2d for collision checking.

Comment: To be completely honest, Im not very experienced so Im up to anything understandable for the sake of doing things right. I wouldnt like to do it all over again because I didnt chose the right approach so go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have proper collision detection between the player and other objects .intersect() is not good enough. It will either make your character permamently stuck in the structure or make it pass through it without player control, which depends on what behavior you code for this condition.

What would work is detecting from which direction the player is approaching the object, and based on that either make him be moved back a bit or set the speed to 0 if current velocity would take him deeper into the structure.

For example, using intersect() as you are, for case of player colliding with a wall from the left:

```
if(velocity.x > 0 && player.getLocalBounds().intersect(wall.getLocalBounds()) && player.getLocalBounds().left > wall.getLocalBounds().left)
```

Then you can use this condition to either stop the player (set the velocity.x to 0), set reverse it so he backs off or do any other kind of behavior you'd wish in the event of a collision.

(Note this is not an ideal solution, but it should work and follow similar logic you've implemented.)